# Best practice guide for writing a updateservice on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking for a guide for write a update mechanism for Windows 7. 
I currently have a software wich 2.exe files. The first one looks for a webservice and if a update is there loads it as tempfile and runs the other exe. the other one overrides the main exe with the update and starts the new version. Could I do this without running both in Administration mode?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to run the updating program as a service.